# Integration on the boundary of fundamental domain of Full modular group

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, modular-function

Suppose $f(x+iy)$ is a function satisfying exponential decay for every fixed x. Then can I conclude that integration on the boundary of fundamental domain of Full modular group (i.e. $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$) is zero.
Actually I need this while proving self adjoint property of weighted hyperbolic Laplace operator on the space of Maass cusp form with petersson inner product.
Thanks in advance for any hint/help

Comment: Presumably you mean _oriented_ integral, so the integral on the left side has opposite orientation to that on the right side, so cancel. by invariance under $z\to z+1$.. And the left half of the bottom arc cancels the right half, because of the invariance under $z\to -1/z$. Is this what you want? Or is there some other obstacle?

Comment: @paulgarrett  Yes Sir! I mean oriented integral. But I am not getting how integral on the arc is zero because orientation will be either clockwise or anti-clockwise on arc?

Comment: The oriented integral over the two halves of the bottom arc self-cancels, because $z\to -1/z$ maps the left half to the right half and _reverses_orientation_. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett  Thanks Sir I got it! you are very helpful. Sir I want to ask one more thing: If we deal with congruence subgroups of full modular group then we may have cusps of fundamental domain other than point at infinity, In that case can we also conclude that function satisfying exponential decay  has zero integration on the boundary of fundamental domain of subgroup?